# ttf-mscorefonts-installer will not install, download error

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

I am trying to download the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` packages on Ubuntu 18.04.

But I am getting an error on downloading the installer.

This is what shows on the terminal

```
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arialb32.exe
Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arialb32.exe
  Redirection from https to 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mirrorproblem?failedmirror=kent2.dl.sourceforge.net' is forbidden [IP: 212.219.56.185 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the fonts/final/arialb32.exe  Redirection from https to 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mirrorproblem?failedmirror=kent2.dl.sourceforge.net' is forbidden [IP: 212.219.56.185 443]
E: Download Failed
Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.6ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.12.6-0ubuntu2) ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this workaround that solves the problem for me:

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

Additionally I set the older version to hold:

```
sudo apt-mark hold ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

That prevents further updates.

Comment: sadly this url isn't available anymore, you need to switch to 3.7

Answer (score 2):

I replace all "http" with "https" in `/usr/share/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and run `/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader`, then it works!

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to the internet.
2. Run this command below:

> `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

This command will reinstall the package and download the files needed to configure the package.