# I can nopt install ttf-mscorefonts under kubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

I try to install microsoft fonts as it is written here https://www.ostechnix.com/install-microsoft-windows-fonts-ubuntu-16-04/

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

and

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

and even restarted the OS
I thought that is all.

and I see this package installed : https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVZvd.jpg

But I do not see any additive fonts like Times, Courier

I found directory /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts, but it is empty.

Did I miss some steps ?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the post-install script failed after installing ttf-mscorefonts-installer, check [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55226009/3664231) to see if it helps.